# How can every real number be expressed as an infinite sum of rationally weighted Hurwitz zeta values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

On the wiki on [rational zeta series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series), it is stated that - given a real number $x$ - it can be represented as follows:

$$ x = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} q_{n} \zeta(n,m). \tag{1} $$ Here, $q_{n}$ is a sequence of rational numbers, the value $m$ is fixed, and $\zeta(s,m)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function). It is furthermore asserted that *"it is not hard to show that any real number $x$ can be expanded in this way"*.

Evidently being a less talented mathematician than the author of the piece, I haven't been able to find a proof of this assertion yet. I did find a way to expand any *rational* number $y$ as described in equation $(1)$. We can do so as follows:

Observe that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \zeta(n,2) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} [\zeta(n)-1] =1. \tag{2} $$

If we then proceed to multiply both sides of the equation with a rational number $y=a/b \in \mathbb{Q} $, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{b} &= \frac{a}{b} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} [\zeta(n)-1] \newline
            &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \Big{(} \frac{a}{b} \Big{)} [\zeta(n)-1] . \tag{3}
\end{align*}

So now we have $q_{n} = a/b$ for all $n \geq 2$.

**Questions**

1. How to prove that any number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ can be represented as described in equation $(1)$ ?
2. Suppose we restrict ourselves to the case $m=2$. Is it then still possible to expand every real number this way?

Comment: You can construct recursively the $q_n$ so that the sequence of partial sums gets closer and closer to $x$. for example choose $q_N$ so that the $N$-th partial sum is at a distance $\le 2^{-N}$ from $x$.